# Is $f(x) = x^2$ injective on $N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is $f(x) = x^2$ injective on $\mathbb{N}$?

$f: \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$

A function is injective if and only if distinct elements of its domain map to distinct elements of its range.

That is, if $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$, OR equivalently, if $x≠y \Rightarrow f(x) ≠ f(y)  $

$x^2 = y^2 \Rightarrow x = y $

$x≠y \Rightarrow x^2 ≠y^2$

The solution from a collegue is saying $f$ is injective because $f(x) = f(y)$ iff  $x^2 = y^2$ iff  $x = y$
(roots are defined for any square) iff x = y

I don't understand this solution, can anyone please assist to resolve this proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x^2=y^2$, then $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=0\,$ but $\,(x+y)\neq 0\,$ and so $\,x-y=0.$

Hence, $x=y$.

Comment: 'but (x+y)≠0' is deduced from x=y which is the same as x-y=0 right?

Comment: No, $x+y\ne 0$ is true since both are positive. @secuaz

Comment: How can we know both are positve? 0 is an element of $N$ right?

Comment: @secuaz Even if you define $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of non-negative integers (e.g., as in France), you still get the conclusion. If $x+y=0$, then $x=y=0$; otherwise, $x+y\neq 0$, and so...

Answer (score 2):

From $f(x)=f(y)$ we have $x^2=y^2$ so $(x-y)(\underbrace{x+y}_{>0})=0$ so $x-y=0$ so $x=y$.

Comment: Looks like Federico beat you by a few seconds.  I was here when he posted the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ f(x)=x^2$ is injective in $\mathbb{R^+}$ and thus itbis injective also in $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R^+}$.

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

$f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}.$

$f(n)= n^2.$

Function is strictly increasing hence injective

Let $m = n+ k \gt n$, $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, i.e. $k$ is a positive integer.

Then for $m >n:$

$f(m)=m^2= (n+k)^2 = n^2 +(2nk +k^2) > $

$n^2 = f(n). $

Strictly Increasing hence injective.